# If I dump and reimport the "mysql" database of a MariaDB install, will all users and privileges be restored?

Tags: mariadb

I'm managing a Debian server with a MariaDB install that has weird issues – some tables seem to become corrupt for no reason, and only in specific databases, some websites have trouble accessing their database, and MariaDB won't even start without the option [`innodb_force_recovery=3`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-recovery-modes/), which  is apparently not a great idea. These problems all started when the server's hard drive suddenly became readonly, which indicates that there was something wrong with it and that some data may have been corrupted,

Anyway, my best idea now is to completely uninstall MariaDB, including deleting the files in `/var/lib/mysql`, reinstall it and reimport all my data from a dump (`mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases`).

My question is, if I do this, will this also restore the users and privileges, which seemed to be stored in the `mysql` database?

Bonus question: if something goes wrong when trying to reimport my data, will simply restoring the original content of `/var/lib/mysql` make everything work again?

The MariaDB version is:
`mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.38-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`

Answer (score 0):

After trying myself in a virtual machine: the answer to both questions seems to be "yes".